# Check the existed record but the record is existed in database and return false result when dd()

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a problem that the record I want to check if that day we have already check in or not. If we check on that day and no scan_in_time, should return false, otherwise it returns already check in.

This is my code below when I write to check if the check_in attendance is existed or not using attendance_date and scan_in_time

```
public function checkinExists(){
      $check_attendance = Attendance::whereDay('attendance_date', request('day'))
          ->whereMonth('attendance_date', request('moth'))
          ->whereYear('attendance_date', request('year'))
          ->whereNotNull('scan_in_time')
          ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->user_id)
          ->exists();
        dd($check_attendance);
      if(!$check_attendance){
        return response()->json(
          [
            'message' => 'No checkin'
          ]
        );
      }else{
        return response()->json(
          [
            'message' => 'Checked in'
          ]
        );
      }
    }
```

When I use dd($check_attendance) and POSTMAN return false, but the record is existed in database. How can I improve the code in here, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be like this and also make sure the format of the date is proper. Check you are passing request object properly.  I hope this will work

```
 public function checkinExists(Request $request){
      $check_attendance = Attendance::whereDay('attendance_date','>=', 
request->day)
          ->whereMonth('attendance_date','>=', request->month)
          ->whereYear('attendance_date','>=', request->year)
          ->whereNotNull('scan_in_time')
          ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->user_id)
          ->exists();
        dd($check_attendance);
      if(!$check_attendance){
        return response()->json(
          [
            'message' => 'No checkin'
          ]
        );
      }else{
        return response()->json(
          [
            'message' => 'Checked in'
          ]
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: "Illegal operator and value combination." I received this error message

Comment: The query if i removed this '>', the result return no checkin, even the record is existed in database]

Comment: i am not sure the query is wrong or i set wrong because attendance_date i set is date (Y-m-d). basically if this query pass the WhereDay, whereMonth, whereYear it should return true with exists(). But this one return false, i dont get it

Comment: i am using JWT Authentication with Token